# Create database with JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, jpa

When I create (using JPA - java persistence api) a persistence unit and then persistence entities they auto create the corresponding tables and fields in the database.

**Can I also make it to auto create the database (if it doesn't exist)?**

My objectif is :

I mean it creates inside the database the tables and fields, but not the database, and if the database hasn't been created before (by hand) - everything fails. So before running the project (which will auto generate the tables and fields if needed) I first must create (by hand) a database.

I use : Eclipse (Java, Hibernate, Flex/Air), MySQL

Thanks for all information

Comment: see http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1853

Comment: While I understand the intention, I find this to be a very bad idea. Personally, I wouldn't use the same user for the application than the user used to create a database.

Answer (score 10):

The database has to be created manually (Fortunatly you didn't ask why ;-). Which is similar to the user/password combination you use to connect to your database server, which must already exist in order to connect to the DB.

Answer (score 5):

My solution to this problem was to add the following right before I create my entity manager:

```
  Connection connection =
      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=" + DB_USER);
  Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
  stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + DB_NAME);
```

You'll need to either surround that with a try/catch block or add a throws SQLException notation to the function in which it exists. So, for example, here is my `initEntityManager` function:

```
public static void initEntityManager() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection =
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=" + DB_USER);
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + DB_NAME);
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

Comment: To avoid unicode issues I recommend you to make your query like this: "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + DB_NAME + " CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci"