# Java automatic creation of database

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am new in Java and I want to do something similar to EF in .NET.
So, is there any way to automatically create a database in MySql local database every time someone runs an app on new PC without password or username?

I tried doing this

```
Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=rootpassword"); 
                Statement s=Conn.createStatement();
                    int Result=s.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE databasename");
```

Comment: please post whatever you tried so far.

Comment: The equivalent of Entity Framework is the [Java Persistence API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm), or JPA.  However, I don’t think it can automatically create or upgrade databases.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942085/create-database-with-jpa.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Database Schema Creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro005.htm), it is a part of the `Java Persistence API`, it gives you the ability to run a set a `SQL` files on the application startup using `javax.persistence.schema-generation.*` properties, and  it connects your application to a default `datasource` if you didn’t provide one. But it is mainly recommended to use in development and testing phases

Usually, you will have to create a `persistence.xml` deployment descriptor that looks like this

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="examplePU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="script"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="script"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="sql/create.sql"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source" value="sql/drop.sql"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="sql/load.sql"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

You can find more examples of using it like [here](http://www.radcortez.com/jpa-database-schema-generation/) and [here](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/standardized-schema-generation-data-loading-jpa-2-1/)