# How to create a database if it does not exist with springboot/JPA and SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jpa

I am surprised I haven't found an SO question that answers this. I am trying to connect a springboot/JPA application to an SQL Server on my local machine. I have the application setup so that it can connect to a database if it it exists, but if I change the JDBC URL to create the database if it doesn't exist then it fails. Here is what the properties look like when it fails.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testing;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true;
spring.datasource.username=hello
spring.datasource.password=Hello1234
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Here is a snippet of the error I receive when starting the app:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user
> 'hello'. ClientConnectionId:971a3369-258b-4713-bddc-cda559b9fe94  at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
> ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.0.jre11.jar:na]  at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandle

If anybody has any thoughts as to how I can change this so the database is created if it does not exist I would be very thankful. Thanks in advnace.

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942085/create-database-with-jpa)?

Comment: I believe I have but that is using JDBC and mysql so I think that one doens't help. I am using spring/JPA and sql-server

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely you can auto-create a database with JPA for that

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testing;
createDatabaseIfNotExist=true;
```

line should be changed to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433
/testing?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a database can be created using JPA.
It has to be created manually or in some other ways, but JPA won't do that for you.

And it would be a bad practice as well to create the database using the application itself, and the use of same credentials.

Answer (score 0):

In practice your application should never create your database so its not really a problem most of the time(Outside small databases like sqlite3).  Different databases would handle this situation differently as well.

In your case I do not see this as a valid jdbc parameter in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-ver15).
I would recommend creating the database in advance with a privileged user separate from your application user.

Comment: I understand that. I agree that it should be created somewhere else and not a good way to go. This is for a POC and would be a lot easier if I can do it like this than the other options given my setup. However this is an option at least on MYSQL and thought that because it's an option there it would be an option here. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html ... Maybe its not possible with SqlServer though.

Comment: Sql Server is typically used in corporate environments where you have dedicated database personnel and managed servers.  Its not really designed to be used in situations that are more informal.  For example until recently just having a copy on your local box was an anomaly due to pricing structures.